# match one or more specific strings in a list

Tags: python, split

I would like to have a function that appends a single or more than two words in one list. For example, I have a list called single_Word consists of four strings:

**single_Word** = ['news in media', 'car in automobile', 'email in technology', 'painting in art']

I would like to the extract 1st word (or basically any strings before '*in*'), so it can return the following output:

['news', 'car', 'email', 'painting']

I have the following code that shows what I intended to do:

```
text_list = []
for text in single_Word:
    x = text.split()
    text_list.append(x[0]) 
print(text_list)
# ['news', 'car', 'email', 'painting']
```

which is fine for me and works as expected, but once I have another list that has more than a single string, it fails to catch that. I know the main reason for that is the x[0], which returns the first element, but how can I change this so it can match more than one string (or any string before 'in'). The following are the lists that I would match on.

**two_Word** = ['news online in media', 'car insurance in automobile', 'email account in technology', 'painting ideas in art']

**three_Word** = ['news online live in media', 'car insurance online in automobile', 'email account settings in technology', 'painting ideas pinterest in art']

**the desired output for 2nd and 3rd lists:**

['news online', 'car insurance', 'email account', 'painting ideas']

['news online live', 'car insurance online', 'email account settings', 'painting ideas pinterest']

Comment: instead of `split`ing in whitespace, use `split(' in ', 1)[0]`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Ma0. it works by using: split(' in ', 1)

```
text_list = []
for text in three_Word:
    x = text.split(' in ', 1)[0]
    text_list.append(x) 
print(text_list)

# ['news', 'car', 'email', 'painting']
# ['news online', 'car insurance', 'email account', 'painting ideas']
# ['news online live', 'car insurance online', 'email account settings', 'painting ideas pinterest']
```